# XML file with custom children nodes

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xmlschemaset

I am actually working with Magento 2 framework which implement XSD schema for his configuration files.
I have a file `flow.xml` where the developer put his an XML mapping and some configurations.
My goal is making two nodes mandatory `mapping` and `options` where the developer can write any XML structure he want.

Here are my actual files :

```
# File flow.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Dnd_Flow:etc/flow.xsd">
    <mapping>
        // Here can be other nodes on X levels (or simply string = bonus) 
    </mapping>
    <options>
        // Here can be other nodes on X levels (or simply string = bonus) 
    </options>
</config>
```

My XSD file looks like this :

```
# File flow.xsd

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="config" type="configType" />

    <xs:complexType name="configType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:????" name="mapping" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element type="xs:????" name="options" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I tried `mixed` values, `xs:all`, differents element types but no result.

This is maybe a piece of cake but I am new at XSD schemas and I am strugguling to find the solution where that there can be everything in my two nodes.

Thank you,
Matthéo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you want is `xsd:anyType`, which you can get either by name:

```
<xs:element type="xs:anyType" name="mapping" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element type="xs:anyType" name="options" minOccurs="0" />
```

or by omitting the `type` attribute:

```
<xs:element name="mapping" minOccurs="0" />
<xs:element name="options" minOccurs="0" />
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks you, exactly what I expect :)